# Looping. Why is this happening? Prime Numbers

Tags: numbers

I'm having a problem understanding the looping, when I put the `System.out.println("Looping: " + i);` at the start of the `for in` method.

It loops three times, more than usual, for example with the number 13, it says:

```
Looping: 2 , Looping: 2, Looping 3.
```

But instead if I put `System.out.println("Looping: " + i);` at the end of the `for in` method, it appears:

```
Looping 2, Loopin 3
```

which is the more accurate to my understanding.

Why is this happening?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++){
      if(isPrime(i)){
          System.out.println("The number: " + i + " is a prime number");
          counter++;
      }

      if(counter==3){
          break;
      }
```

}

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n){
    if(n == 1){
        return false;
    }

    for(int i=2; i <= (long) Math.sqrt(n); i++){
        System.out.println("Looping: " + i);
        if(n%i == 0){
            return false;
        }


}

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect as output? You can debug this program for deeply understanding it

Comment: I'm doing it, the question is why when I print, it does it twice, try with 13 it will do two prints more than usual, look at it.

Comment: `for example with the number 13,`—your code runs for all numbers between 1 and 10, 13 is never processed. Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for which you can provide full output and point to specific places where it behaves wrong in your opinion, without resorting to "if you ignore lines 1-8...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let take this code:

```
  public static boolean isPrime(int n){
    if(n == 1){
      return false;
    }

    for(int i=2; i <= (long) Math.sqrt(n); i++){
      System.out.println("Looping: " + i); // first
      if(n%i == 0){
        return false;
      }

      System.out.println("Looping2: " + i); // second
    }

    return true;
  }
```

It's output is:

```
Looping: 2
Looping: 2
Looping2: 2
```

As you see the first `System.out.println` is 2 times executed and the second only once. It happens because of

```
if(n%i == 0){
  return false;
}
```

If `n%i == 0` gives `true` then the method will `return false` and `for loop` stops executing. This explains why it makes difference where to put `System.out.println`.

More useful information you will get [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decision-making-javaif-else-switch-break-continue-jump/).

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is perfect, by that time I wasn't able to understand, thank you very much though.